# Is there a way to get Apple mail to display like gmail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, catalina, gmail

This might be the wrong forum, but I'll ask anyway.
I set up Apple mail and don't like the display, compared to gmail (in Chrome/Safari).

I like the table layout where I don't see any specific email content until I select the specific email.

Like this
[image]

The closest I can come in Mac mail is this below, but it still shows each emails content.
I know I can slide the window up and down from dragging the dot in between, but that's not what I want.

Is this possible in Mac mail? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple Mail has only classic layout on or off mode.

You can compensate it by turning off the classic layout, making the mail list super wide & use double click to open a mail window & close it with the shortcut.

- Mojave: Mail → Preferences → Viewing → Use classic layout checkbox.
- Catalina: *Show the message list in column layout*: Choose View > Use Column Layout (a tick indicates the layout is in use).

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mail/mlhl7fa3a90d/13.0/mac/10.15

However, if you're looking for alternatives, [Edison Mail](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1489591003)'s GUI is heavily influenced by Gmail's web version. (That was one of the reasons I deleted it.)

Comment: How do I turn off the classic layout?

Comment: I can also install Outlook if I need to as I have a subscription. Do you know if that has it?

Comment: @user1186050 see the edit for 1st comment.

Comment: don't have that option in OS X Catalina...

Comment: @user1186050 I haven't used it. Neither do they show it in the app screenshots on the App Store.

Comment: @user1186050 that is unfortunate. Maybe they moved it around. I don't like classic at all, so it shouldn't be forced.

Comment: @user1186050 see the edit. It's in view menu

Comment: Maybe I didn't give enough detail in my original question, but when I check "Use Column Layout" I still see the bottom half of the mail window displaying the email content. I can unselect the row from above, but there is still the area where the email content resides, it doesn't disappear. That's what I'm trying to remove. So all I see on the page/screen is the list of all emails and the sidebar.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpHAd.png _This_ and what you showed in your ss is all that is possible. I already replied to that in the answer: "*No, Apple Mail has only classic layout on or off mode.*"